# Flushing sqlite journal

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am curios. I use ORMlite in my application. I have added debug function to copy Sqlite database to a file system. It is simple:

```
File in = DatabaseHelper.getDatabasePath();
File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), in.getName());
out.setReadable(true, false);
log.debug("Copying database {} to SD card at {}", in.getName(), out.getAbsolutePath());
boolean result = Misc.copyFile(in, out);
```

But today I have found in a File explorer of the Android Device monitor that it contains two file - `*.sqlite`, and `*.sqlite-journal`. Is there any method in OrmLite (or sqlite) that would force flushing the journal?

This answer says that there is a mode Persist that keeps this file even when all transactions are finished. But I would prefer to call some sync before copying the database file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29696642/1639556